# Double Dimensional Array (Prime(sum) counting flaw)

Tags: java, primes

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array1 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int table[][] = new int[5][5];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j =0; j < 5; j++){
                System.out.println("Write a value for row " +i + " column " +j);
                int n = scan.nextInt();
                table[i][j] = n;
            }
        }
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j =0; j < 5; j++){
                System.out.print(table[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int sum = 0;
        boolean prime = true;
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j =0; j < 5; j++){
                for(int e = 2; e < table[i][j]; e++ ){
                    if(table[i][j] % e == 0){
                        prime = false;
                    }
                }
                if(prime == true){
                    sum += table[i][j];
                }
                else{}
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Sum of all prime numbers in this array is " +sum);
    }
}
```

Well, as the title itself says uhmm The program is supposed to sum up all the prime numbers in the user defined Array table but it's just summing up the first row. i checked up all the brackets, nothing helps. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a 2D array? Is this part of the requirements?

Comment: Also, I suggest breaking this method into several smaller ones. For example, you could have one method that inputs the array of numbers and another method that checks if a given number is prime.

Comment: Your code has two failures: 1. the prime flag (see `rayryeng`s answer); 2. you never close the `Scanner` resource.

Comment: @rayryeng-Closing Scanner is not an error in program and it is rather bad programming practice! Also I did not intend to rant at someone but he challenged such a trivial point to be incorrect that I was kinda forced to repeat!

Comment: @shekharsuman - I understand. We all make mistakes, but you could have approached it more delicately.  I've also removed my answer as the other one modifies the code slightly while I decided to do more cleanup. Probably not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @shekharsuman It is a bad practice to close opend resources? And I mixed up the "special" number that is not a prime (anymore). I  meant 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @shekharsuman - I've never heard of it being bad practice to close a resource once you're finished with it.  Looking at the code, it's obvious that you don't need the resource anymore once you compute the sum of primes, so I don't see why we shouldn't close it.

Comment: @rayryeng You removed your answer so I write it here: you recommended to call `scan.close();`, but I think the better approach would be the try-with-resources statement (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). That way you can't forget to close the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset prime for each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        for (int e = 2; e < table[i][j]; e++) {
            if (table[i][j] % e == 0) {
                        prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime == true) {
            sum += table[i][j];
        } else {
        }
        prime = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is correct and prime must be set to `true` at the end of the prime loop!Also,+1